# CTreeCtrl setting selected item programmatically

Tags: mfc, tree

I want to programmatically set the state of a tree ctrl item to be selected and then process it elsewhere. I want to do this to reuse the code that is called when the user clicks it. I try this but its failing, why?

```
// somewhere in the code

m_tree.SetItemState(hItemToBeSelected, TVIS_SELECTED, TVIS_SELECTED);
CommonFunction();

// elsewhere

CommonFunction()
{
HTREEITEM h = m_tree.GetSelectedItem();// this returns NULL.
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use SelectItem instead of SetItemState: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8hy20sy(v=VS.100).aspx